# Stuck on LearnStreet Ruby Training. Simple Ruby Code

Tags: ruby

Attempting to learn Ruby using the new LearnStreet online tutorials.

Have attempted to get help via their Q&A system but it seems nobody answers them.

> "Can you now implement the withdraw! method on account object, which
>   takes one parameter amount and reduces the balance by the specified
>   amount? After defining the method, go ahead and withdraw 100 dollars
>   from the account and check the balance."

Is the question and I got the two hints of

> " Hint 1 The code @balance = @balance - amount reduces the amount from
>   @balance.
>
> Hint 2 Then call the method withdraw! on the account object -
>   account.withdraw!(100). "

My attempt was

```
def

account.widthdraw!

@balance = @balance - amount

end

account.withdraw!(100)
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Can you now implement the withdraw! method on account object, which takes one parameter amount and reduces the balance by the specified amount? After defining the method, go ahead and withdraw 100 dollars from the account and check the balance."

One step at a time:

- "Can you now implement the withdraw! method on account object

  ```
  class Account
    def withdraw!
    end
  end
  ```
- which takes one parameter amount...

  ```
  class Account
    def withdraw!(amount)
    end
  end
  ```
- and reduces the balance by the specified amount?

  ```
  class Account
    def withdraw!(amount)
      @balance = @balance - amount
    end
  end
  ```
- After defining the method, go ahead and withdraw 100 dollars from the account and check the balance."

  ```
  account = Account.new
  account.withdraw!(100)
  ```

Answer (score 2):

I think you'd want something like this.

```
class Account

    def withdraw! amount
         @balance -= amount
    end

end
```

Comment: To clarify for @user1739696, `@balance = @balance - amount` is equivalent to `@balance -= amount`, for most cases. Defining via `def account.withdraw!` will work in specific cases, but it isn't really right for this case. Also, the big thing you appear to have missed here was the `amount` parameter. (Sorry @alex, not trying to step all over your answer)

Comment: @JimDeville I appreciate the clarification, thanks. I'm not a Ruby expert so your feedback is valued.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to this question:

```
def account.withdraw!(amount)
    @balance = @balance - amount
end
account.withdraw!(100)
```